# Swashbuckle Remote definitions from a jsonschema file

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

How can I use remote definitions in aspnet core 2.0 with swashbuckle? I need to import the json file (schema) to create the definitions in the swagger.json file

**Example swagger.json:**

```
definitions:
  response:
    $ref: "https://localhost/domains/jsonschema#/definitions/response"
```

> How to do it in swashbuckle for .net core 2.0 with c#?

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio-code%2Cvisual-studio-code-xml

Comment: swashbuckle should automatically generate all definitions from all the models used in your API, ... Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: but if I wanted to use a JsonSchema for the entities, how could I tell the swagger that the definitions come from that JsonSchema file?

Comment: You should create models that match your JsonSchema